# Changing Distinguished Name Using Java Naming

Tags: java, active-directory, naming, ldap-query

I am Trying to Change The Group Distinguished name using Java Naming Package
but every Time i get the same error message

```
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    ModificationItem[] roleMods = new ModificationItem[]
            {
                    new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("distinguishedName",DN2))
            };
    ctx.modifyAttributes(DN1,roleMods);
```

And Every time i get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: [LDAP: error code 19 - 000020B1: AtrErr: DSID-030F04A3, #1:
>       0: 000020B1: DSID-030F04A3, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 31 (distinguishedName)

Is it at all posibble to change DN if yes how should i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, renaming in LDAP is not a modification as the change applies to the DN (distinguished name). You more often find examples when you look for rename or the modify DN / modify RDN operation.

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JNDI-LDAP/howtorenameanobject.htm) how to do renames using the JNDI LDAP provider.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks For Helping Me 
I don't think The Rename Would Worked either.
i try This 
            ctx.rename("distinguishedName='"+DN1+"'", "distinguishedName='"+DN2+"'");
But Still I Get the Same Error .

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide the values as well?

Comment: The official JNDI tutorial may also help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/naming/rename.html

 ctx.rename(DN1, DN2)